# Access const with generics C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following base class:

```
public class Base
{
    public string LogicalName { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfChars { get; set; }

    public Base()
    {

    }

    public Base(string logicalName, int numberOfChars)
    {
        LogicalName = logicalName;
        NumberOfChars = numberOfChars;
    }  
}
```

and the following derived classes:

```
public class Derived1 : Base
{
    public const string EntityLogicalName = "Name1";
    public const int EntityNumberOfChars = 30;

    public Derived1() : base(EntityLogicalName, EntityNumberOfChars)
    {

    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public const string EntityLogicalName = "Name2";
    public const int EntityNumberOfChars = 50;

    public Derived2()
        : base(EntityLogicalName, EntityNumberOfChars)
    {

    }
}
```

and I also have this function that is provided by a service:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetEntities<T>(string entityName, int numberOfChars) where T : Base
{
    //Some code to get the entities
}
```

My problem is how can I call this function generically? I want to call it with something that looks like this:

```
public void TestEntities<T>() where T : Base
{
    var entities = GetEntities<T>(T.EntityLogicalName, T.EntityNumberOfChars);

    //some other code to test the entities
}
```

This of course doesn't work because at this point T is not known. How can I accomplish something similar to this? EntityLogicalName and EntityNumberOfChars are characteristics that all Base derived classes have and they never change for each derived class. Can I get them from the Base class without instantiating objects or some other way that I am not seeing?

Comment: Why cant you move these EntityLogicalName and EntityNumberOfChars  to base class then..

Comment: Because they are different for each derived class and their purpose is not to be used as instance properties but as type constants (or static). The method TestEntities only knows which entity type to get but I need to pass those constants to the method.

Comment: Okie then, since you are always assiging them to base variables you can simply use var entities = GetEntities<T>(T.LogicalName , T.NumberOfChars ); right?

Comment: No, because T is a type and not an instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, I believe using constants here is a bad design decision.

You can either solve the issue using @vittore approach, but for me it sounds like you should use meta-programming with attributes if you're looking to get data from the `T` generic argument

For example, what about:

```
public class LogicalNameAttribute : Attribute
{
     public LogicalNameAttribute(string name)
     {
          Name = name;
     }

     public string Name { get; private set; }
}

public class NumberOfCharsAttribute : Attribute
{
     public NumberOfCharsAttribute (int number)
     {
          Number = number;
     }

     public string Number { get; private set; }
}

[LogicalName("Name1"), NumberOfChars(30)]
public class Derived1 : Base
{
   public Derived1() : base()
   {

    }
}
```

Now your service method can extract attribute metadata as follows:

```
public void TestEntities<T>() where T : Base
{
    LogicalNameAttribute logicalNameAttr = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<LogicalNameAttribute>();
    NumberOfCharsAttribute numberOfCharsAttr = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<NumberOfCharsAttribute >();

   Contract.Assert(logicalNameAttr != null);
   Contract.Assert(numberOfCharsAttr != null);

   string logicalName = logicalNameAttr.Name;
   int numberOfChars = numberOfCharsAttr.Number;

   // Other stuff
}
```

There's a performance penalty because you need to use reflection to get attributes applied to `T`, but you gain the flexibility of not forcing derived classes to provide this static info.

Comment: While there are ways to reduce that performance penalty to negligible level, bigger issue with this approach that you have kind of twisted design of your class library, there is no way to require you to add those attributes to new derived class. That is why I am not a fan of this particular use of attributes.

Comment: @vittore Yes, I don't advocate this approach as the best one, but I wanted to provide an alternate approach...

Comment: I know, didn't write this to argue, just my 5 coins on attributes. In general metaprogramming allow to solve you a lot of issues in a more elegant way, just in this particular case I feel there is a need for a language to have a way to express consent that derived classes have to have attributes.

Comment: I think this is closer to what I need because I really need to get the data from the T generic type.

Answer (score 5):

Replace constants with getter abstract properties

```
public abstract class Base
{
   public abstract string LogicalName { get; }
   public abstract int NumberOfChars { get; }

   public Base()
   {

   } 
}


public class Derived1 : Base
{
   public string LogicalName { get { return "Name1"; } } 
   public int NumberOfChars { get { return 30; } } 

   public Derived1() : base()
   {

    }
}
```

Also, you will be able to put some logic into overriden getter, e.g. :

```
...
public string LogicalName { get { return this.EntityMap.Name; } } 
...
```

UPDATE: The fact that you do not want to instantiate object from class but want to be able to get that string in a strongly typed manner can be handled in one more way. It is totally separate from answer above ( Since you can't override static props in c#). Consider the following code. We are adding one more class here, but LocatorInner can be a member of BaseClass. We are using this approach a lot in several existing apps.:

```
public class Locator
{
    public static class LocatorInner<T> where T : BaseClass
    {
        public static string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static string GetName<T>() where T : BaseClass
    {
        return LocatorInner<T>.Name;
    }

    public static void SetName<T>(string name) where T : BaseClass
    {
        LocatorInner<T>.Name = name;
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{

}

public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    static DerivedClass()
    {
        Locator.LocatorInner<DerivedClass>.Name = "me";
    }
}

public class TestClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public void Method()
    {
        var name = Locator.GetName<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like the `override` keywords are missing in `Derived1`

Comment: But that way in order to pass those properties to GetEntities I would have instanciate a Derived1 object. EntityLogicalName and EntityNumberOfChars are constants. Is like saying that a car is a vehicle and has a NumberOfWheels of 4 without having to construct a car to know that. On the other hand a motorcycle is also a vehicle and has a  NumberOfWheels of 2. All vehicles should have a static member that represents the number of wheels but I don't know how to express that. Also I need to be able to get those members from a generic type that inherits from vehicle.

Comment: @budahead not sure what is your issue with this example. You will have two derived classes one for car one for bike and one will have `public int NumberOfWeels { get { return 4; } }` while another `public int NumberOfWheels { get { return 2; } }`. However if you need to work on a class level, not instance level, ie you do not want  to construct instance of the class , just make those properties static.

Comment: @vittore that's what I did but instead of static I made them const. But my issue is the same, in TestEntities how do I get the 'NumberOfWheels' from T? As a side note TestEntities is to be called dynamically to a list of derived classes, which means I can't pass the 'NumberOfWheels' as a parameter to TestEntities (I should have started with a car-vehicle as an example instead of Base and Derived :) ).

Comment: In the TestEntities, with my code you will have `(new T()).NumberOfChars`. The only thing you will need to have constrain `public IEnumerable<T> GetEntities<T>(string entityName, int numberOfChars) where T : Base, new()`

Comment: That's what I have been using but I thought I could get away without having to instantiate any objects.

Comment: @budahead Then just use static properties.

Comment: In the TestEntities how can I access the static properties from T?

Comment: @budahead check my updated answer with one more technique.

Comment: I have tried your new suggestion and it works to some extent. In order to work, those static constructors have to run and for them to run for each class I have to create an instance of each derived class or reference some other static members of the derived class first. I upvoted your answer but I am going to use @matias attributes technique, it's closer of what I was expecting and it's easier to explain to others that might be using the code after me. Thank you very much for your time, I have consolidated some concepts with this problem.

Comment: Right, you will have some code running on application start, just once. Good luck with your way, and once you done , please post your solution here, so others will see your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

As @vittore mentioned, move the properties to base,pass the hard coded values from derived and in creation use just defautl(T)

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetEntities<T>(string entityName, int numberOfChars) where T : Base
{
    yield return default(T); //Is its always class use new constraint and return new T();
}
```

Comment: GetEntities comes from a service I don't have access to it.

Comment: There will be some place where you are giving value to the T. From that place pass the entity name.public void TestEntities<T>(string entityLogicalName,int entityNumberofChars) where T : Base
{
    var entities = GetEntities<T>(entityLogicalName, entityNumberOfChars);

    //some other code to test the entities
} //calling code where actual type is given...TestEntities<Derived1>(Derived1.EntityLogicalName,Derived1.EntityNumberofChars);

Comment: TestEntities is to be called dynamically to a list of derived classes, which means I can't pass the EntityLogicalName explicitly as a parameter to TestEntities.

Comment: Do you have any sample where I can see the issue? Its little difficult to understand from explanation.

Comment: I will have a List<Type> and then I am going to iterate that list and for each type I will call TestEntities. So TestEntities will be called dynamically and from this point I don't have access to NumberOfChars. That's why I need to get it from T in TestEntities. You can use the code I posted, just implement GetEntities to return some populated list of the appropriate type.